# passing selected date in dropdown list back to controller many options

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I had a look at all the related questions but am still unsure. I am a noob and still learning.

I have the view:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("TradeUKKPISearchesDataExtract", "Report")) //action/controller
  { %>
  <div style="padding: 10px; background-color: #eeeeee; width: 250px; border: 1px solid #cccccc;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 100px; padding-top: 3px;">
      <p style="color:Red"><%: Html.DropDownList("Choose a Sunday: ", ((DateTime[])ViewData["Sundays"]).Select(day => new SelectListItem() { Text = day.ToString(), Value = day.ToString() }), "--Select--")%>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:right; width: 272px; padding-top: 30px;">
    <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="Search" />
  </div>
```

when I hit the submit button, where do I set the value that needs to be returned?

in html.BeginForm or in Html.DropDownList?

my action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TradeUKKPISearchesDataExtract(DateTime date)
{

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  sb.AppendLine("Title, Total");

  var reportData = _reportingService.GetTradeUKKPISearches(date);
  foreach (var item in reportData)
  {
    sb.AppendLine(String.Concat("\"", item.Key, "\", ", item.Value));
  }

  byte[] textBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());

  return File(textBytes, "application/csv", "TradeUKKPISearchesDataExport.csv");
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `Html.DropDownList()` is the HTML element's name and that is how the selected value is identified during the form submit. So you should have it like this

```
<p style="color:Red">Choose a Sunday:<%: Html.DropDownList("date", ((DateTime[])ViewData["Sundays"]).Select(day => new SelectListItem() { Text = day.ToString(), Value = day.ToString() }), "--Select--")%>
```

to have the `date` parameter in your action method correctly populated.